# Flag items not having the specified combination in a column

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012, ssms

I need to flag ID#s not having a specified combinations of DC and Storage Locations. For example:

Articles must have the following combinations for each DC:

| DC | Storage Location |
| --- | --- |
| DC01 | ABC, BCA, DCA |
| DC02 | ABC, BCA |
| DC03 | ABC, DCA |

My desired outcome would be the below as I'd like to show the Storage Location missing.

| ID# | DC# | Storage Location | Flag |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | DC02 | ABC | Good |
| 1 | DC02 | BCA | Good |
| 2 | DC01 | ABC | Bad |
| 2 | DC01 | BCA | Bad |

The bad entries are because of the missing 'DCA' entry. So far I have the below however I can't figure out how to count the number of matches per ID (i.e. must be 3 for DC01 so that the flag would be Good else Bad). Once the flag is figured out the only thing I can think of is to do a union (one select statement for each combination) - is there a more optimized way to do this?

```
select
ID,
DC,
Storage_Location

FROM table
where 
DC = 'DC01' AND Storage_location in ('ABC', 'BCA', 'DCA')
group by ID, DC, Storage_location
```

The table contain multiple ID, and each ID having different combinations:

| ID# | DC# | Storage Location |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | DC02 | ABC |
| 1 | DC02 | BCA |
| 2 | DC01 | ABC |
| 2 | DC01 | BCA |
| 3 | DC03 | ABC |
| 3 | DC03 | DCA |

Comment: I don't fully understand what your table looks like. You are showing a desired result with IDs. Can you show the original table data too, so I see from where you are coming?

Comment: @ThorstenKettner Thank you for responding, I've attached the original table with some sample data

Comment: Tag your question with the database that you use.

Comment: Do you have the desired location combinations in a table? Also, what is the version of SQL Server?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `STRING_AGG` to see whether data is complete. For instance:

```
select
  id, dc, location,
  case when
  (
     select t.dc + ':' + string_agg(t2.location, ',') within group (order by t2.location)
     from mytable t2
     where t2.id = t.id and t2.dc = t.dc
  ) in ('DC01:ABC,BCA,DCA', 'DC02:ABC,BCA', 'DC03:ABC,DCA') then
    'GOOD'
  else
    'BAD'
  end as status
from mytable t
order by id, dc, location;
```

The subquery is necessary, because there exists no analytic version of `STRING_AGG` yet in SQL Server.

Comment: Thank you but however when I tried I got a 'The function 'string_agg' may not have a WITHIN GROUP clause.' error message. I think might be some syntax issue within the subquery ( in ('DC01:ABC,BCA,DCA' ...)

Comment: No, that's not an issue with the subquery. I've put my query in forpas' demo (only adapted column names) and it works properly. Please see https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=d26adbbcae9f075e1b5e4c2512c69a1f. Both our queries are working and they use about the same technique. `WITHIN GROUP` for `STRING_AGG` is also mentioned in the docs (https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/sql/t-sql/functions/string-agg-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15). What SQL Server version are you using?

Comment: You get the version with `select @@version;`.

Comment: Microsoft SQL Server 2012 (SP4) (KB4018073) - 11.0.7001.0 (X64)   Aug 15 2017 10:23:29   Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation  Enterprise Edition: Core-based Licensing (64-bit) on Windows NT 6.3 <X64> (Build 9600: )

Comment: This explains it. SQL Server 2012 is a very old version. It doesn't feature `STRING_AGG`. Maybe a good time to upgrade. Otherwise, you could look up the Internet on how to emulate `STRING_AGG` in SQL Server 2012.

Answer (score 2):

Use a CTE that returns all the `DC`s and their desired `StorageLocation`s and join to the table.
Also aggregate in the table and use `STRING_AGG()` (requires version 2017 of SQL Server) to collect for each `DC` their actual `StorageLocation`s in a comma separated list and join this query also:

```
WITH cte(DC, StorageLocation) AS (
  SELECT 'DC01', 'ABC,BCA,DCA' UNION ALL
  SELECT 'DC02', 'ABC,BCA' UNION ALL
  SELECT 'DC03', 'ABC,DCA'
)
SELECT t.*, CASE WHEN s.DC IS NULL THEN 'Bad' ELSE 'Good' END Flag 
FROM tablename t INNER JOIN cte c
ON c.DC = t.DC
LEFT JOIN (
  SELECT DC, STRING_AGG(StorageLocation, ',') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY StorageLocation) StorageLocation 
  FROM tablename
  GROUP BY DC
) s ON s.DC = c.DC AND s.StorageLocation = c.StorageLocation
ORDER BY t.ID, t.DC, t.StorageLocation;
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=1edbdf4101a6d398f8aa044cf4837813).

Comment: Thank you @forpas however unfortunately this code will need to be ingested in another program that can't handle CTE. Is there another way to do this without creating a CTE?

Comment: I previously tagged as ms-sql however mine is is actually mssq V18.4. Agologies for the confusion. It looks like this version does not support String_agg